# How to get the number of days within a range of dates in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the days that an employee works and the days that he rests, according to @fechaDesde - @FechaHasta that is entered from a screen and the date of Jornada_Ini (Day of Work start)
[image: Pantalla]

My Table Start Home Screen:
[image: Jornada_Ini]

The employee has the Day 2x1 (2 days work 1 rest), are 8 Types of Days, another employee has the Day 8x2 (8 days work 2 rest).
I'm working with the employee of Jornada 2x1

With the following code

```
DECLARE @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime
set @FechaDesde='2015-03-10 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2015-03-31 00:00:00.000'
SELECT CC.NumOperador,
j.Descripcion as Jornada,
(DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(@FechaDesde), MAX(@FechaHasta)) + 1) AS TotalDias,
((DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(@FechaDesde), MAX(@FechaHasta)) + 1))/3 AS DiasDescansados,
(DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(@FechaDesde), MAX(@FechaHasta)) + 1) - (((DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(@FechaDesde), MAX(@FechaHasta)) + 1))/3) as DiasTrabajados
FROM trkOperadores O
JOIN trkJornada J ON O.cveJornada = J.cveJornada
JOIN CopCalendario CC ON O.NumOperador = CC.NumOperador
WHERE O.cveTipoOperador = 2 
AND O.NumOperador = 900200
GROUP BY  j.Descripcion, cc.NumOperador
```

I get the total of days, 7 days rested and 15 days worked, which is correct
With the calendar below.

[image: Calendario]

Beginning of the day 10 to the day 31 of March, those that are in green color are days worked and the orange ones are the rested, the one that is in Red color is lack but still I will not restare to the days worked for which it is correct The result 15 worked 7 rested

But what happens if my Date of Entry was the 8th of March and on my screen to generate the report I request the report from the 10th to the 31st of March without counting the date of entry

[image: Calendario2]

Then there would be 14 days worked, there I do not count the fault (since it is on a day off from work so I stay because I change the dates to explain a little bit) and I would be rested 8.

What I can do to take into account my Jornada_Ini and to be able to obtain the result as it is in the calendar.

I hope to see me explained !!

Comment: PLEASE, provide details for us. There could be a number of ways to deal with this. It sort of depends on what your data looks like and what you want as output. See this article. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ or this one...https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This looks a LOT like the one you asked last week and didn't give us much information there either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241732/how-to-display-business-days-between-a-range-of-dates-in-sql

Comment: So Jornada_Ini is the first workday of the time period? Where does that value come from?

Comment: That's right, it's registered in the copcalendario table

Comment: You know if you took 10 minutes to provide the table definition and some sample data this would already be answered right? It really isn't that difficult but is challenging with no table to work with.